# Using triggers during form submission with google apps script in google forms?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm currently working on this google form where one of the question asks for a start and end date and uses the calendar function. My goal is once the user sets the start date, when the user opens the calendar button to click on the end date, the end date would start on the start date. Right now when the user clicks on the start date, the end date will start on the current date. I've looked into using triggers for google forms but they only execute on form submit or open. Are there any add-ons that can allow you to execute a trigger while the user is giving input to the start date.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can interact with Google Forms programmatically, I would use a webapp and build my own form.

Comment: I know google apps script can interact with google forms, there are specific functions you can use. However, you can't create a trigger while the form is being built I was wondering if there was any add-on that can do this?

Comment: What functions? Do you have a link? I’d like to learn more.

Comment: Sorry I might be using the wrong words to describe it. I know with google app script you can automate scripts that can be integrated with sheets, forms and google apps. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/ here is a link that I have been using.

Comment: I've created forms with scripts but I believe that once they run...they run on their own and I believe that you can't make interactive changes to the form once their running.  But hey I could be wrong and Google is constantly updating things so I could be way behind the times.  That's why I asked.